# Setting the base url of an ASP.NET app behind a proxy server

Tags: asp.net, iis, proxy

I have the same issue as the poster of this question
[Running ASP.NET MVC application behind a proxy with different root relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591490/running-asp-net-mvc-application-behind-a-proxy-with-different-root-relative-path)

except that I'm running "classic" ASP.NET 4.0 in IIS 7. Basically, the application is deployed to http://machine/MyApp, but it is being accessed through a proxy server as: http://someotherMachine/**SomeDirectory**/MyApp. So, ASP.NET thinks that /MyApp is the root, but in this case it really isn't. Is there some magical setting of ASP.NET or IIS that I can set telling it, "Hey, by the way the **root** of this application is actually SomeDirectory not MyApp?"

Comment: Can you give more details? What does not work in your asp.net web application?

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I am going through this right now and I have not found anything easy...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a directory like SomeDirectory on your web server, set that as the root application, and then create a virtual directory under SomeDiretory that points to MyApp?